# How to create a private bitcoin network using bitcore?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcore

I'm trying to create a private bitcoin network using bitcore. But bitcore sync's data either with bitcoin livenet or testnet. I couldn;t find any bitcore documentation which will allow me to create a network from scratch.

I followed the instruction from below link

https://bitcore.io/guides/full-node

```
{
  "network": "livenet" or "testnet" || what do i have to put for private network?
  "port": 3001,
  "https": true
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat the tag information in the title of the post. The tagging system here works extremely well and doesn't need help. Redundantly adding (tag) or [tag] information is just clutter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your custom info in the `bitcore-node.json` which is created in your node directory

```
{
  "network": "livenet",  // your coins network name
  "port": 3001,          // your coins port
  "services": [
    "bitcoind",          // required services
    "web"
  ],
  "servicesConfig": {
    "bitcoind": {
      "datadir": "/home/user/.bitcoin",         //your coins directory
      "exec": "/home/user/bitcoin/src/bitcoind" //your coins executable
    }
  }
}
```

So changing

```
"network": "livenet"
```

to whatever yours is called should do the job. Now you should be able to run your custom node with a different network.